# Different objects with same distance have different disparity after rectification

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

In my application, I use two cameras with different focal lengths to form one stereo system. The functions from OpenCV are used to perform stereo calibration and rectification. After rectification,  I find two objects with same distance from the cameras have different disparities. The difference is significant. The RMS of stereo calibration is about 0.2. When I calibrate the cameras, the target is about 0.4m away. The two objects is about 1.3m away from the cameras. Can this cause the problem? Is the reason that accuracy of ration matrix R and translation T between two cameras retured by the function StereoCalibrate is not enough?

Comment: Disparity should be related to the depth (Z coordinate) rather than the distance. If an object is not exactly in front of the camera, its distance is something like X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2, I suppose. Are your object both in front of the camera (exactly in front of the camera, X=0, Y=0)?

Comment: @marcoresk The baseline is short, so this is not a problem.